# How to send api response to UIViewController using Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am updating my collectionView with a response from my api using Combine to provide real time info. My api returns NSArray which is working but for some strange reasons inside my SearchAPI class I can receive the response and print it out in the console **print("Our array ", searchArray)** but can't sink to my UIViewController and update my collectionView accordingly. **print("value ", value)** Value is always empty

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class SearchAPI {
    static let shared = SearchAPI()
    
    func fetchData(url: String, category: String, queryString: String) -> Future<NSArray, Error>{
            var searchArray: NSArray = []
            let urlString = url
            print("url come ", urlString)
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
                fatalError()
            }
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [weak self] data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    return
                }
                
                do{
                    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSArray
                    if let responseJson = json {
                        searchArray = responseJson
                        print("Our array", searchArray)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            task.resume()
            return Future { promixe in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    promixe(.success(searchArray))
                }
            }
        }
}

//In my UIViewController

    var observers: [AnyCancellable] = []
    let action = PassthroughSubject<NSArray, Never>()
    var category = "tv"
    var queryString = ""
    private var models: NSArray = []
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if isMovieSelected {
            btnMoviesBottomBorder.backgroundColor = .secondaryPink
            btnAlbumsBottomBorder.backgroundColor = .systemGray
            btnAlbumsBottomBorder.backgroundColor = .systemGray
        }
        txtSearch.searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchItem), for: .editingChanged)
    }
    @objc func searchItem(){
        moviesView.alpha = 0
        albumsView.alpha = 0
        booksView.alpha = 0
        lblSrchResults.alpha = 1
        queryString = txtSearch.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
        print("who is calling ", queryString)
        let url = "https://endpoint?category=\(category)&query=\(queryString)"
        SearchAPI.shared.fetchData(url: url, category: category, queryString: queryString)
                    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                        switch completion {
                        case .finished:
                            print("finished")
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print(error)
                        }
                }, receiveValue: { [weak self] value in
                    print("value ", value)
                    self?.models = value
                    self?.searchCollectionView!.reloadData()
                }).store(in: &observers)
        
        
    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Fetched ", models.count)
        return models.count
    }
```

Comment: You don't do anything with the received `value`; you need to assign it to whatever property is providing the data for your collection view

Comment: You mean I need to assign it to a property before I can access it?

Comment: Yes. At the moment it is a local variable that is thrown away as soon as the closure is complete. There must be some array property that you use in your `cellForItemAt` function.

Comment: I have created an NSArray ```var models: NSArray = []``` variable and assigned the value to it but still retuning empty. Kindly check my edit

Comment: ```print(models.count)``` at ```numberOfItemsInSection ```is always returning 0

Answer (score 0):

In your `fetchData` function, you create a `dataTask` to run the URL request.  At some point later on that dataTask will complete and return an array.

Then you create a `Future` and send some code off to run on the main queue.  That code has nothing inside of it to make it wait until the `dataTask` completes.

The code inside the `Future` is going to run "right away" and complete before a value has been assigned to `searchArray`.

You need to change your `Future` so that it only resolves (only completes) after the `dataTask` is done.  Just tweaking your code a bit it looks something like:

```
    func fetchData(url: String, category: String, queryString: String) -> Future<NSArray, Error>
    {
        return Future { promixe in
            var searchArray: NSArray = []
            let urlString = url
            print("url come ", urlString)
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
                fatalError()
            }
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                guard let data,
                      error == nil else {
                    promixe(.failure(error!))
                    return
                }
                
                do{
                    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSArray
                    if let responseJson = json {
                        searchArray = responseJson
                        print("Our array", searchArray)
                        
                        promixe(.success(searchArray))
                    }
                }
            }
            
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

I typed this into a playground, but I did not run it, so additional changes may be necessary.

All of the action now happens inside the future.  Once you are in a future block then you should call its resolution function (in your code called `promixe`) for all success or failure cases.

I changed your code so that `promixe` is called ONLY when the data task completes (successfully or unsuccessfully).

For your code you should probably also:

- Be sure to call `proximate`, once, on every path through your `Futures` block.  In particular you need to catch the error that `JSONSerialization` might give you and called `promixe` to report the error.  Otherwise your future may not complete if data comes back from the server, but it cannot be parsed.
- Change your code to use Swift style JSON instead of using `JSONSerialization` that way you will have an `[SomeType]` instead of `NSArray`.  Use the type system to your advantage to reduce the possibility of errors.
- Instead of doing `queryString = txtSearch.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")` use
  `txtSearch.text!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)`. It will cover more cases if the user types
  something unexpected.